# Find UTF-16 code for a character in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file with data in Chinese language for instance i have a character 攻 and I want to find the utf-16 code of this character. how can i find it in python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ord` function.

```
print(hex(ord(u'攻')))
```

prints `0x653b`

Comment: can we find utf-16 with this method?

Comment: That is the UTF-16 code for the character - '\u653b'

Comment: sorry actually i have very little knowlegdge about encodings so

Comment: A little misleading, though happens to return the correct value. `ord()` returns code points for unicode strings. It just happens that the code point in question encodes as single UTF-16 16 bit code unit and  has equal numerical value. Could've been mentioned in the answer.